# How to set environment variables in AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template with a section named `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment`.

Despite its name containing the word "**Environment**", there appears to be no place in this section to add Environment Variables for the application.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my CFN files I use the [aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkapplicationenvironment) to set the env variables (only relevant part shown):

```
EBConfingTemplate:
  Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
  Properties: 

    OptionSettings: 
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
        OptionName: MY_ENV_VAR1
        Value: my-value1
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
        OptionName: MY_ENV_VAR2
        Value: my-value2
```